# how "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header works

Tags: http

I have very basic question regarding the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.
Assume that we have a website "www.siteA.com" that will be doing the CORS to another site "www.siteB.com" and the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" on siteB is set as "www.siteC.com" only.

When user via browser access siteA and it tries accessing content from siteB, what will the response look like?

Will the request be blocked at the server level

or

will it send the entire response with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header set to "www.siteC.com" and will be blocked by user's browser? (i think the first is the correct one)

Comment: It's the second one. The server doesn't know the domain of the page sending the AJAX request (and it could easily be forged). CORS restrictions are implemented by the browser checking the header that the server sends back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When user via browser access siteA and it tries accessing content from siteB, what will the response look like?

The same as any other response from the site.

> Will the request be blocked at the server level

No. CORS is an instruction to the browser that it should not apply the Same Origin Policy to the request. The server can't (reliably) tell where a request came from to block it at the server level.

> will it send the entire response with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header set to "www.siteC.com" and will be blocked by user's browser?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

> will be blocked by user's browser?

Yes, because only www.siteC.com domain can access the resource according to your Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. They would send back;

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.siteC.com

You can find answers the questions about the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header via [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-access-control-20080912/#preflight-request).